# Hide Default lang id in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-2

I'm using Codeigniter 2 and i want to know how to hide  hide lang id for default language : `www.domain.com/page.html` and for other languages i can make it as normal like `www.domain.com/es/page.html` , `www.domain.com/fr/page.html`,?

Answer (score 0):

hi use this lang library can solve this problem

[multi lang library](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/225196/)